# DevExpress-Wpf LayoutItems with different sizes

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress-wpf

In my project I have LayoutControls inside these Controls are LayoutGroups and these Groups have LayoutItems in them, my problem is I dont want to set the width of the LayoutItems I want that they get there width automatically. So at the moment all my Layoutitems have the same size inside the Group but I want that Layoutitems with more Content grow and the others should shrink is this possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxayg.png)
In the picture you can see that inside the Group there is a Label with a lot of Content but it doesnt get more space than the others

Thanks in advance
NG

Comment: With such questions, try posting some example code that you have tried or you are stuck with.

Comment: @Aditya I hope this picture helps

Comment: My bad, I got the scenario wrong initially.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use flexi model. Add display: flex to Groups and flex: 1 to the Layoutitems. also give flex direction to the group.